# Read excel file cannot find the path?

Tags: r, excel, import

```
library("readxl")

my_data <- read_excel("GVA.xlsx")
my_data
```

however the console says the path does not exist. 
How can I import excel/csv files and know that the file will always be found.

Why does this not work?

p.s.
I am new to R

Comment: You need to make sure your current working directory is in the same directory as GVA.xlsx if you want this to work. See `?setwd` or Session > Set Working Directory if you are in Rstudio. Or you can provide the full path e.g. `read_excel("C:/Users/MyName/Downloads/GVA.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, is 'GVA.xlsx' in your working directory?  If not, R can't find it because you're not mapping to anything outside of your current directory.  You can navigate to the file by clicking on: File > Import Dataset > From Excel.  Browse to your file and set any required import options.  R will actually create the code to map to the file in question.